# Vue loses prototypes and imported files when creating new component

Tags: vue.js

When extending a Vue component to a modal, a new Vue instance is generated. This leads to losing all pre-imported helpers/ Vuex-stores etc.

Is there a way how to copy all data to the new extended Vue component?

To make it clear, have a look at this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L9h8cujz/).

It confronts you with an alert. When you click on the button, the modal is opened. But if you look at my code, another alert should be fired. But $hi() is not available in the other Vue instance.

I create a component like this:

```
const createComponent = (props) => {
    const wrapper = document.createElement('div');

    const Component = Vue.extend(MyComponent);

    return new Component({
        propsData: {
            props,
        },
    }).$mount(wrapper);
};
```

I'm using [SweetAlert](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/) as a modal.

So I add this like:

```
swal({
    content: createComponent(props).$el,
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you move the line

```
Vue.prototype.$hi = () => alert('hi');
```

above

```
let component = new TestComponent().$mount(wrapper)
```

it will work. Your first component references `$hi()` before it's defined.